# Allow user to cancel adding of an entry in C# WinForms DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, validation, datagridview

I have decided to use `DataGridView` in-place editing in my `C#` `WinForms` application. I want to let the user add a new row and when he moves away, store that row in the database. In this current situation, there is only one column. Also, each entry should be unique.

If he enters some unique value in there, the row gets validated and all works well. If he enters a duplicate value, in the `RowValidating` event I would set `e.Cancel = true` and show an error `MessageBox`.

The problem is that if he starts adding, but then changes his mind and doesn't want to add anymore, there's no way for him to cancel it other than closing the form.

I tried adding this to the `RowValidating` event, but it doesn't allow clicking anywhere else other than the current row:

```
if (dgv_Industries[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(dgv_Industries[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString()))
{
    e.Cancel = true;
    return;
}
```

If I don't set `e.Cancel = true`, but just `return`, it moves on to trigger the `RowValidated` event. I could abort the database operation here but I would be stuck with an empty row (aside from the standard empty add row) in the `DataGridView`, as below, which not only looks wrong, it also makes my functionality crash (unless I implement more checks).

[image: Empty row example]

Then I tried doing this in the `RowValidated` event but it yielded an `Operation cannot be performed in this event handler.` exception:

```
dgv_Industries.Rows.RemoveAt(e.RowIndex);
```

**What would be the correct way of allowing the user to cancel the addition of a new row, while also removing the row it created?**

Comment: What are you using as the datasource?

Comment: It's not bound to anything because of the shortfalls of DataBinding the DataGridView in WinForms. The data is extracted programmatically from a MySQL database.

Comment: I believe by pressing *esc* it deletes the row automatically

Comment: You are in fact correct. A small note is that I was overriding the OnUserDeletingRow event, which gets triggered when pressing Esc, which hid the very functionality I was looking for. Please post this as an answer so I can award it. Thanks.